# How to specify size when taking screenshot in wkhtmltoimage?

Tags: php, size, screenshot, wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltoimage

This is my first time using wkhtmltoimage. I am trying to take screenshots of urls. But I need the images to be of width 1024 and height 768; is it possible? Currently it is giving me an image of width 1024 and height 431.

The command I am current using is

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltoimage.exe  --width 1024 --height 768" http://www.google.com/ D:/example.jpg
```

but it is saying:

> '"C:/Program Files (x86)/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltoimage.exe  --width 1024 --height 768"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I am using quotations because I using Windows localserver.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this,

```
C:\Program" "Files" ("x86")"\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltoimage.exe  --width 1024 --height 768 http://www.google.com/ D:\example.jpg
```

or

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltoimage.exe"  --width 1024 --height 768 http://www.google.com/ D:\example.jpg
```

you need to combine single parameter as single string.

Comment: That first example is an interesting method, is there any advantage to that instead of a single combined quote? Thanks to you I noticed the invalid slashes in my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltoimage.exe" --width 1024 --height 768 http://www.google.com/ D:\example.jpg
```

You might need quotations around google and example too.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the path of your wkhtmltoimage.exe to your `PATH` environment variable.

Thus, you could call your wkhtmltoimage from everywhere just like that :

```
wkhtmltoimage --width 1024 --height 768 http://www.google.com D:\example.jpg
```

1. Execute `control sysdm.cpl`
2. Click on the `Advanced system settings` tab
3. Then `Environment variables`
4. Edit the `Path` system variable, and add the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf` to it.

Then restart your console, and execute your command.